# Up all night Hoshanah Rabbah: why?

Tags: halacha, minhag, evening-night, sleep, hoshana-rabbah

Why do we stay up all night on Hoshanah Rabbah, and what is its source?

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7854.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but pretty sure the original source(s) is Kabbalistic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taamei Haminhagim (citing Machazeh Avraham, by R. Avraham of Buczacz) [says](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&pgnum=369) that it is because the ushpiza for the seventh day of Sukkos is King David, and he used to stay up all night studying Torah - so we do the same to evoke his corresponding Divine attribute.

R. Chaim Vital (Pri Eitz Chayim and Shaar Hakavanos, cited in [Nitei Gavriel](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46442&pgnum=354)) give a different reason: because it is the last night before the final "sealing" of our judgment for the year.

Comment: IMHO, it would help to add to the second answer (based on HaRav Hayim Wital) that, because "it is the last night before the final 'sealing' [...]", we stay up all night specifically *to study Torah or perform other mitzwot* in an effort to increase our merits before "the final 'sealing' of our judgment".