# Where does the custom of staying up all night on Shabbat originate from?

Tags: shabbat, minhag, history

I heard there were some Tzadikim who would stay up all night on Shabbat where did this custom originate from?

Comment: You'll find sources here - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7855/22152